# The scroll for my div doesn't appear using Prototype js lib and slider module

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I have a website at http://work.juanalvarezdj.com/  and I want to add a slider to the transparent field (div) below. I am using the prototype js and slider. Can someone please take a look at the source and tell me what's wrong? The slider seems to always be disabled..

Comment: You have jQuery included, might that be [conflicting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was because it was being resized dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of problems. Firstly the slider3 object is disabled and secondly the DIV that contains it (with id 'wrap3') is hidden (display: none).

If I run `slider3.setEnabled();` in the console and then remove the `display: none` style (using Chrome developer tools) the slider appears and becomes responsive to mouse drag events (it still doesn't seem to behave quite right though).

So it looks like the problem stems from this bit of JavaScript:

```
if ($('scrollable2').scrollHeight <= $('scrollable2').offsetHeight) {
  slider3.setDisabled();
  $('wrap3').hide();
}
```

This code is getting called before the resize code when the offsetHeight is always going to be at least as large as the scrollHeight. So I think you should probably move this bit of code to the resize event handler. You will also need to handle the case in which the slider needs to be re-enabled. e.g.

```
if ($('scrollable2').scrollHeight <= $('scrollable2').offsetHeight) {
  slider3.setDisabled();
  $('wrap3').hide();
} else {
  slider3.setEnabled();
  $('wrap3').show();
}
```